# Google Static Maps Custom icons of Markers shows only 4 markers . i have hosted icons but they are still not accessable from google api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I was working on google static map api . I have hosted 22 icons for marker of size 23x23 . After sending request i get only 4 icons on map. Why google api is not recognizing my hosted icons after 4. Here is my URL request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x600&markers=icon:http://202.71.128.192/GoogleDropImages/Start.png%7C25.7708021,87.5366466&markers=icon:http://202.71.128.192/GoogleDropImages/0.png%7C25.768615,87.4750018&markers=icon:http://202.71.128.192/GoogleDropImages/1.png%7C25.7713015,87.4810162&markers=icon:http://202.71.128.192/GoogleDropImages/2.png%7C25.7712895,87.4811087&markers=icon:http://202.71.128.192/GoogleDropImages/3.png%7C25.7754794,87.4853834&markers=icon:http://202.71.128.192/GoogleDropImages/4.png%7C25.7756112,87.485494&markers=icon:http://202.71.128.192/GoogleDropImages/14.png%7C25.7759498,87.4847748

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behavior, you can use only 5 different custom icons. This fact is [documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Markers)

> You can use up to five unique custom icons per request. This limitation does not mean that you are limited to only 5 marked locations on your map. Each unique icon may be used with more than one markers location on your map.

This [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825584) was raised in the public issue tracker.